# case when else mysql with same column with multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql, case

I've a table data . I'm trying to get the data based on three  where conditions for the same column using case when mysql query .
But not giving the results as expected .
My table :

```
id  bundle_id   asset_id    price_id    customer_id  weekday_am     weekend_am 
1       1           1           1                       100.00          120.00
2       1           2           1                       150.00          140.00
3       1           1           1                       0.00            0.00
4       1           1           2                       0.00            145.00
5       1           2           2                       140.00          0.00
6       1           1           2                       0.00            0.00
7       1           1           3           5           140.00          120.00
8       1           2           3           5           0.00            140.00
9       1           1           3           5           130.00          0.00
```

and i want the results as like below formatted.

```
bundle_id   asset_id    weekday_am      weekend_am
1           1               140.00          120.00
1           2               150.00          140.00
1           1               130.00          0.00
```

But my query is not working :

```
SELECT bundle_id,asset_id ,
(CASE 
WHEN weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00  where customer_id = 5 and price_id = 3 THEN weekday_am
WHEN weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00 where price_id = 2 THEN weekday_am  
ELSE weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00 where price_id = 1 THEN weekday_am  
END as 'weekday_am'),(CASE 
WHEN weekend_am IS NULL  or weekend_am = 0.00 where customer_id = 5 and price_id = 3 THEN weekend_am
WHEN weekend_am IS NULL  or weekend_am = 0.00 where price_id = 2 THEN weekend_am  
ELSE weekend_am IS NULL  or weekend_am = 0.00 where price_id = 1 THEN weekend_am  
END as 'weekend_am')
FROM 
bundle_prices where bundle_id = 1
```

Can somebody  please help me with this ? Thank you .

Comment: I'm getting error like this  `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where customer_cid = 5 and price_id = 3 THEN weekday_am ELSE weekday_am IS NULL ' at line 3`

Comment: Where customer id = 5 seems to be all that you need. If not, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry : yeah error is there at where customer_id = 5 i'm not getting how do i solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

try to edit

```
WHEN weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00  where customer_id = 5 and price_id = 3 THEN weekday_am
```

to

```
WHEN weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00  and customer_id = 5 and price_id = 3 THEN weekday_am
```

or

```
ELSE weekday_am
```

and the same with weeken_am

Comment: same error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where customer_id = 5 and price_id = 3 THEN weekday_am WHEN weekday_am IS NULL  ' at line 3`

Comment: But its giving null values now . I need to check if `weekday_am` is having value at the condition `customer_id = 5` and `price_id = 3`  if it doesn't have then i have to check the condition `price_id = 2` , even if this does not have i need to check the condition where `price_id =1`

Comment: How do i use when else condition in this scenario ?

Comment: how come you get the result in the table when the condition is weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00

Comment: if the condition is weekday_am IS NULL  or weekday_am = 0.00 you will always get value of weekday_am  is NULL or 0.00.check your condition again.maybe it's something like weekday_am IS NULL  or weekend_am= 0.00

Comment: Yeah thats where  i'm trying to apply this where conditions to ge the weekday_am

Comment: I need to apply the same condition for `weekday_am` and `weekday_pm`